# How to bring back library functions which have been deleted?

Tags: python

Suppose I do this

```
import cmath
del cmath
cmath.sqrt(-1)
```

I get this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'cmath' is not defined
```

But when I import `cmath` again, I am able to use `sqrt` again

```
import cmath
cmath.sqrt(-1)
1j
```

But when I do the following

```
import cmath
del cmath.sqrt
cmath.sqrt(-1)
```

I get this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sqrt'
```

Even when I import `cmath` again, I get the same error.

Is it possible to get `cmath.sqrt` back?

Thanks!

Comment: @detly - No intention. I am just learning Python and I was playing with the interactive compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need [reload](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reload)

```
reload(cmath)
```

... will reload definitions from the module.

```
import cmath
del cmath.sqrt
reload(cmath)
cmath.sqrt(-1)
```

... will correctly print ..

```
1j
```